# CSS pseudo selector on drop down menu

Tags: css, html, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I am using the CSS :before pseudo-selector to create a block above the first item in a drop down list.  I've been having trouble getting this block created with the pseudo-selector to be the same width as the <li> above it.

For example when you hover over "About" the pseudo block that appears beneath it should be the same width as the block that contains the word "About" and so on for the other 3 blocks.

Here's a fiddle to what I have got so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/jh67P/

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="main">
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul class="secondary">
                <li><a href="#">Learn About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nice things to know</a></li>
            </ul>        
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="secondary">
                <li><a href="#">Product One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product Two</a></li>
            </ul>        
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a>
            <ul class="secondary">
                <li><a href="#">Something Nice</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another nice thing</a></li>
            </ul>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's the CSS:

```css
nav .main {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.main > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.main > li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.main > li a:hover {
    background: #3b3b3b;
    color:#FFF;
}

.secondary {
    display:none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.main li:hover .secondary {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.main li:hover ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.main > li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }

.main > li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}

.main  li:hover ul:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:10px solid #1e7c9a;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent; 
}
```

Edit:  Using absolute positioning I was able to achieve the effect.  Here's the updated CSS.

```css
nav .main {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.main > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.main > li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.main > li a:hover {
    background: #3b3b3b;
    color:#FFF;
}

.secondary {
    display:none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.main li:hover .secondary {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
}

.main li:hover ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.main > li:hover a { background: #3b3b3b; }
.main > li:hover li a:hover {
     background: #1e7c9a;
}

.main > li:hover:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    border-bottom:10px solid #1e7c9a;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent; 
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    margin-left:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing:

```
.main  li:hover ul:before {
```

To:

```
.main > li:hover > a:after {
```

Is that what you are after?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jh67P/6/)

Comment: Almost.  I was trying to see if I could get the pseudo-element to appear between .main > li and  .secoondary > li

So when .main > li is hovered it shows the pseudo-element, and then the .secondary <ul> list underneath that.  Sorry if I'm not explaining it well.  I was just reading about pseudo-elements and I was seeing if I could use on to style a drop downow list.

Comment: You are not explaining it well, it currently does show the pseudo-element only when `.main li` is hovered, and then it shows the `ul.secondary` directly underneath that. So the pseudo-element is in the right place between the `.main li` and the `.secondary li`. It was already like that in your original fiddle, all I changed was the width of the pseudo-element to be as wide as the block which has the word 'About' in it. So what is not right yet?

Comment: I've edited the answer, as the previous line made the pseudo-element appear after every `a` in a `li`, now it only adds it after `a` when it is in a `li` which is a direct descendant of `.main`.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/jh67P/5/

This is close to what I was trying to do.  Hover over "About" for example.  I'd like the psuedo-element to appear above the ul.seconday > li elements.  In the updated fiddle the psuedo-element is appearing as if it were inside them.  Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Above every single `li` inside `ul.secondary` or only above `ul.secondary`? In the jsFiddle in my post it does appear above the 'ul.secondary', not inside it.

Comment: Above every single `li` inside `ul.secondary`

Comment: And it needs to be as wide as? the `.main li` above it?

Comment: Yes.  This is my first attempt at using a psuedo-selector like this so perhaps I am not using it correctly?

Comment: Yes, you can only do that with fixed widths, there is no way that pseudo-elements inside a `ul` under an `a` tag can inherit the width of the `a` tag, or the containing `li` tag for that matter.

Comment: I think I may have gotten it using absolute position on the pseudo element, and on the `ul.secondary` elements.  This is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nirvanachain/jh67P/

Comment: I probably could have done that, that's not "above every single `li` inside `ul.secondary`" which was your answer to my earlier question, but "only above `ul.secondary`". Try to be more clear next time.

Comment: I see do see that.  Thanks for your help!